# How to make sure all elements contain a specific class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check to make sure that all certain elements that are children of their parent container have a specific class. Can someone tell me how to do this in jQuery?

if all paragraph tags of div tag have the class "correct"

-> yep, all of them have the class

otherwise, not all paragragh tags in div tag have that class

-> noope, they all do not have the required class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean **direct** children, then:

```
if ($('div').children('p').length === $('div').children('p.correct').length) {
  // yes
}
else {
  // no
}
```

To include all descendant `<p>` tags in the reckoning, use ".find()" instead of ".children()".

*edit* — it'd be keen to have a plugin for stuff like this:

```
$.fn.all = function(pred) {
  var rv = true;
  this.each(function(element) {
    if (!pred(element)) return (rv = false);
  });
  return rv;
};
```

Then you could write:

```
if ($('div p').all(function(p) { return p.hasClass('correct'); })) {
  // yes
}
```

A similar ".any()" function would be useful too.

Comment: Thanks, no-- they are not direct children.

Comment: @Cofey ok then use ".find()" - also, if your page is really big, a custom bit of code to avoid two separate jQuery page scourings would be faster. If the page isn't too big and this isn't something that runs frequently, then you won't notice a performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doTheyReally() {
    return $('parentSelector').children('p').size() == $('parentSelector').children('.correct').size();
}
```

**edit**

And [here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnQUk/) you can test with this code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A few ways spring to mind (as is often the case with jQuery)

One, count the number of paragraph tags inside the div tag `$('div').find('p').length` and compare it with the number of paragraph tags inside the div *with the required class* `$('div').find('p.class').length`

The second way that springs to mind, is to use the jQuery filter() method:

```
var childParagraphs = $('div').find('p');
if (childParagraphs.length == childParagraphs.filter('p.class').length)
{
    // true
}
```

You can also pass a callback function to the filter() method if you need more complex rules (as opposed to "has-class")

Yet another way that springs to mind is to check for the existence of elements that do not match the "has-class" selector.

```
if ($('div').find('p').not('.class').length == 0)
{
    // true
}
```

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: @Cofey Just noticed your comment below, updating to use find() in examples.